# Error creating bean with name 'validator'

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm trying to create bean validation (I'm using tomcat server 7). When I added this piece of code

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return new org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

I got the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in Config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have looked over all the same issue and added needed dependencies as below:

```
<dependency org="javax.el" name="el-api" rev="2.2.1-b04" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-el-api" rev="8.5.14" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-jasper-el" rev="8.5.14" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.validation" name="validation-api" rev="2.0.0.Final" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="6.0.0.CR2" conf="compile->default"/>
```

But the issue still occurs.

Please help me,
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you don't have 2 different incompatible versions of `javax.el`. Try to geneate dependency tree to see conflicts.

For example:

```
<dependency org="javax.el" name="el-api" rev="2.2.1-b04" conf="compile->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-el-api" rev="8.5.14" conf="compile->default"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-jasper-el" rev="8.5.14" conf="compile->default"/>
```

could provide different version of api.

Try to remove `javax.el` also.

Comment: I have tried to remove the javax.el also but It doens't work. :(

Comment: Chcek if dependencies provides different version of javax.el and javax.validation (spring, tomcat, hibernate) and adjust these dependencies.

Comment: oh, thanks so much. So I'm using Tomcat 7, which version should I start?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [getting started](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) page of Hibernate Validator. It looks that you are trying to use HV 6.0, it depends on 3.0 version of javax-el (if you are using EL for message interpolation). And you are adding 2.2 version. So it might be a reason why you see that error. Also there's a Final version of HV 6.0 released so you can use it instead of CR2.

It should be enough to have:

```
<dependency org="org.glassfish" name="javax.el" rev="3.0.1-b08" conf="compile->default"/>
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="6.0.1.Final" conf="compile->default"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, so much. I'll try it

Comment: I changed it and receive this error:
Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed

Comment: it's hard to say what's wrong with such small amount of information. I assume the error you've mentioned is a top level one. If so, there should be a reason why it failed to create that bean...